# Whatsapp Databases inside android device

Tags: applications, internal-storage, whatsapp-messenger

Whatsapp is keeping some database files in internal memory, inside the folder `/WhatsApp/Databases` in the format `"msgstore[date].db.crypt8"`.

Will my chat history be gone if I delete those files? Are these files important?

I am using an unrooted Xiaomi phone.

Please give more information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whether my chat history is got deleted, if I delete these files?. Is
>   this files are important?

These are important files and If you delete these then your backups are gone.

These files are the **Local backups** of your `WhatsApp` and this local backup is run automatically every day at 2 AM and save your database in a file on the phone itself.

> Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup
>   files, hence you are seeing the file names corresponding to the dates
>   of last 7-days.

You can back up your chats and media to Google Drive, so if you switch Android phones or get a new one, your chats and media are safe. To use Google Drive, make sure the following is true:

- Your device must be synced with **Google Drive**.
- Your Google Drive account must have enough space for all of your `WhatsApp` data.
- Your phone must have enough free space to create the backup.

Check [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/fi/android/20887921) of WhatsApp for more information.

**Additional Note**: If you delete these database files, your backups are gone. But the chat history in `whatsapp` itself remains untouched because the database is in still in use. So any chat data is still available for the user - just the backups are gone.

Comment: will the files get removed, If  I stored it to Google Drive?

Comment: Like you said - these files are for backup purposes. If you delete them your backups are gone. But the chat history in whatsapp itself remains untouched because the database is in use. So any chat data is still available for the user - just the backups are gone :P maybe you can clarify this and add it to your answer?

Comment: @RahulGopi You can check the details on FAQ Link I posted. It seems like back up is kept on local phone and on Google Drive, so they will not be removed. But as said in FAQ, Your phone will store up to the last 7 days worth of local backup files.